# Problema con post_per_page en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy haciendo una página en Wordpress y la idea es mostrar en ciertas plantillas post que tengan determinada etiqueta.
Ya logre filtrar por la etiqueta, el problema es con **post_per_page**, no logro que me muestre la cantidad indicada...
Una vez que logre que muestre solo 3, pasaré a hacer el paginado. Pero ese ya es otro tema.
Paso el código

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Relaciones institucionales
*/
get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) :

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                 <?php
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif; 

            wp_reset_postdata();
          wp_reset_query();
?>

            <div class="container">
            <?php

            $query1 = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_per_page' => '3',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category_name' => 'institucional',
                'order' => 'DESC') );  ?>

        <ul class="row columna-actividades">

            <?php while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
                 $query1->the_post();

                 get_template_part( 'pdm-templates/actividad-columna-sin-etiqueta', 
                 get_post_format() );
            } 
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>

        </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

De antemano agradezco cualquier aporte que me puedan hacer
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Me auto contesto después de una larga búsqueda
Encontré la solución en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782381/custom-post-per-page-not-working

La gráfica y simpática respuesta: **posts_per_page** and not **post_per_page** my friend

Para hacer clara la respuesta, es posts, con s final

Saludos!